# LWJGL glBufferData is too slow to allocate

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, voxel

I've been struggling with this for a few weeks now. I'm making a voxel game that generates 16^3 chunks as a single interleaved buffer to render. I've offloaded most of the work to a ThreadExecutor but there's OpenGL lag that I just can't eliminate.

The below code is my Chunk class (ChunkMesh.java), it's constructor is called on another thread, and it's `init` function is the function that runs on the main thread to initialise the OpenGl data. It needs to take under a millisecond but it's regularly taking 5 or more and rarely freezing for over two seconds, which is unacceptable.

I'm not super experienced with OpenGL and none of the other threads related to voxel games that I've found have the same issue as me, nor are their solutions applicable. Please, if anyone has some insight, help me.

```
package client.engine.graphics;

import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.GL_TEXTURE0;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.glActiveTexture;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;


public class ChunkMesh {
    private int vaoID;
    private List<Integer> vboIDList;
    private int vertexCount;
    public Material material;

    private float[] interleaved;
    private int[] indices;

    public ChunkMesh(float[] positions, float[] texCoords, float[] normals, int[] indices) {
        vertexCount = indices.length;
        vboIDList = new ArrayList<>();

        this.indices = indices;

        long buffTime = System.nanoTime();

        interleaved = new float[positions.length + texCoords.length + normals.length];
        int ind = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < positions.length / 3; i++) {
            interleaved[ind++] = positions[i*3];
            interleaved[ind++] = positions[i*3+1];
            interleaved[ind++] = positions[i*3+2];

            interleaved[ind++] = normals[i*3];
            interleaved[ind++] = normals[i*3+1];
            interleaved[ind++] = normals[i*3+2];

            interleaved[ind++] = texCoords[i*2];
            interleaved[ind++] = texCoords[i*2+1];
        }

        buffTime = System.nanoTime() - buffTime;
    }

    public void init() {


        FloatBuffer interleavedBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(interleaved.length).put(interleaved).flip();
        interleaved = null;
        IntBuffer indicesBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt(indices.length).put(indices).flip();
        indices = null;

        vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        int vboID = glGenBuffers();
        vboIDList.add(vboID);

        long allocTime = System.nanoTime();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, interleavedBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        int stride = (3 + 3 + 2) * 4;

        //Position VBO
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, stride, 0);

        //Normals VBO
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, stride, 3 * 4);

        //TexCoord VBO
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, stride, 6 * 4);

        allocTime = System.nanoTime() - allocTime;
        float totalMs = allocTime / 1_000_000f;
        if (totalMs > 5) System.err.println(totalMs);
        else System.out.println(totalMs);

        //Index VBO
        vboID = glGenBuffers();
        vboIDList.add(vboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        MemoryUtil.memFree(interleavedBuffer);
        MemoryUtil.memFree(indicesBuffer);
    }

    public int getVaoID() {
        return vaoID;
    }

    public int getVertexCount() {
        return vertexCount;
    }

    public void initChunksRender() {
        Texture texture = material.getTexture();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getID());
    }

    public void endChunksRender() {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    private void initRender() {

        //Draw the mesh
        glBindVertexArray(getVaoID());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    }

    private void endRender() {
        //Restore State
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void render() {
        initRender();
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        endRender();
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        //Delete the VBOs
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        for (int vboID : vboIDList) {
            glDeleteBuffers(vboID);
        }

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glDeleteBuffers(vaoID);
    }

    public void deleteBuffers() {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        //Delete the VBOs
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        for (int vboID : vboIDList) {
            glDeleteBuffers(vboID);
        }

        //Delete the VAO
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you profile to check that `glBufferData` is the problem and not the memory allocation on the CPU? I'd also suggest not creating new buffers during runtime but build a buffer pool.

Comment: @BDL I did, the memory allocation occasionally goes above 1 millisecond but by far the biggest time sink is the glBufferData, you can see my benchmarking in the pasted code, where I define and print allocTime

Comment: @httpdigest It definitely appears that GC is a problem, I ran my program in VisualVM and it detected a lot of garbage collection occuring when chunks are generated. I don't know what to do about that though, as I need an OpenGL context to make the mesh and I need to store the arrays until then...